# Setting the timeout of a websocket in javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a websocket that I open at the beginning of my client side application and send messages to throughout the life of the application. Currently the socket naturally timeouts after 1 minute. Looking at the API there doesn't seem to be a settimeout function for me to increase this. Is there a way to do this on a websocket?
Thanks

Comment: Im also looking for this solution